# asp.net with c# base64 not display the images

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I use asp.net with c# when i save the image as database it's ok no problem.
This my code in asp.net, i upload multiple files

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

and c# code is :

```
 foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
                {
                    int imgLenght = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    byte[] img = new byte[imgLenght];
                    HttpPostedFile file = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                    file.InputStream.Read(img, 0, imgLenght);
                    project.uploadImage(img, newID);
                }
```

When i retrieve the images from database i use the base64

```
public string GetImage(object img)
    {
        return @"data:image/jpg;base62s," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])img);
    }
```

But the picture doesn't display, i don't know what is the problem ?
I saved image as extension jpg and png.

As asp.net with repeat

```
 <div id="sliderProject">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>
                 <div class="imgshow">
                 <img src="<%# GetImage(Eval("Imagecontent")) %>" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry i write base62s this not in my code but i test this for show the error

Comment: in my code base64 this